# Multiple variables in django rest framework detail route

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to add a detail route in django rest framework that uses multiple variables in the url. I have attempted to set a custom `url_path` but my django server crashes with an exception when I do so.

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: "^some-object/(?P[^/.]+)/my_route/(?P[a-z0-9]+)/(?P[a-z0-9]+)/$" is not a valid regular expression: redefinition of group name 'pk' as group 2; was group 1

This is the detail route that I have so far.

```
@detail_route(url_path='my_route/(?P<pk>[a-z0-9]+)/(?P<other_pk>[a-z0-9]+)')
def my_route(self, request, pk, other_pk):
    from rest_framework.response import Response

    # ...

    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

My goal is to be able to access this endpoint from a url with a format like:

`.../my_route/2/4/`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The group name of the pattern immediately after `some-object` is also `pk`?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye, I think you nailed it. It looks like I am overriding another pk variable in the url. I believe that is why I'm seeing this error.